# Drop down calendar control

Tags: asp.net

How is the asp.net calendar control displayed in a popup window and how is the selected date displayed inside a Textbox control?

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax Control Toolkit calendar is good:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Also, there is a JQuery UI one which is nice:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/